# array reduce with an object as accumulator

Tags: javascript

with

```
let str = "baaabbabbsbsssssabbaaaa";
```

with this

```
[...str].reduce((characterMap, char) => {
    if (!characterMap[char]) characterMap[char] = 1;
    else characterMap[char]++;
    return characterMap;
}, {})
```

I get    { b: 8, a: 9, s: 6 }

But when I shorten it to this,

```
[...str].reduce((characterMap, char) => !characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++, {});
```

It prints out 1 instead of { b: 8, a: 9, s: 6 }

Why?

am I using reduce wrong in the first place?

Comment: please add what you get and want you want.

Comment: Shorten it to what?  One line?  That makes it less readable.

Comment: I've updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how do I shorten this?

By:

1. Not trying to shoehorn it in to a `reduce`. :-) `reduce` is appropriately used when the accumulator value *changes*. In your case, it doesn't.
2. Not using an array wrapper. Strings are iterable, so use that fact directly.
3. Using the [curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html)¹ to default the character count if not present.

Just use a loop:

```
const characterMap = {};
for (const char of str) {
    characterMap[char] = (characterMap[char] || 0) + 1;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
let str = "baaabbabbsbsssssabbaaaa";
const characterMap = {};
for (const char of str) {
    characterMap[char] = (characterMap[char] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(characterMap);
```

But if you **really** want to use `reduce`, you can apply the `||` trick and use a shorter name:

```
const characterMap = [...str].reduce((acc, ch) => {
    acc[ch] = (acc[ch] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Live Example:

```js
let str = "baaabbabbsbsssssabbaaaa";
const characterMap = [...str].reduce((acc, ch) => {
    acc[ch] = (acc[ch] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log(characterMap);
```

You can (ab)use the comma operator to force that into a concise arrow function, but at the cost of readability and maintainability (IMHO).

> But when I shorten it to this,
>
> ```
> [...str].reduce((characterMap, char) => !characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++, {});
> ```
>
> It prints out 1 instead of { b: 8, a: 9, s: 6 }
>
> Why?

Because your callback function returns the result of `!characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++`, not the object. So subsequent calls to it get that number, not the object, and `characterMap[char]` is always false (because `1["a"]` is `undefined`, etc.).

---

¹ *(on my anemic little blog)*

Comment: I wasn't sure of when's appropriate to use reduce and how || worked, but now I do. thanks

Comment: @totalnoob - FWIW, I wasn't trying to get you to change your accepted answer. The key thing is just to understand the ramifications of the various approaches from various perspectives (readabiity, maintainability, memory churn...). Anyway, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the returned accumulator as result.

```js
var str = "baaabbabbsbsssssabbaaaa",
result = [...str].reduce((characterMap, char) => {
    characterMap[char] = (characterMap[char] || 0) + 1; // take default value of zero
    return characterMap;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

> But when I shorten it to this,
>
> ```
> [...str].reduce((characterMap, char) => !characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++, {});
> ```
>
> It prints out 1 instead of `{ b: 8, a: 9, s: 6 }`
>
> Why?

Simply because in the first loop

```
!characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++
```

it takes this route

```
!characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
true                  characterMap['b'] = 1
```

returns `1`

and in all following iterations, you take the number `1` and try to get a property `a` (or all following letters of the string) of this number, which is `undefined`

```
!characterMap[char] ? characterMap[char] = 1 : characterMap[char]++
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
!1['a']
true                  1['b'] = 1
```

The result is `1`

Comment: The simple loop is much less complicated, and shorter.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the arrow-expression syntax, you can use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator):

```
[...str].reduce((characterMap, chr) => 
    (characterMap[chr] = (characterMap[chr] || 0) + 1, characterMap), {});
```

Or you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
[...str].reduce((characterMap, chr) => 
    Object.assign(characterMap, {[chr]: (characterMap[chr] || 0) + 1}), {});
```

Comment: ahh, nice trick. so this is a way to return the original obj in a one liner

Comment: Indeed, in both cases the expression returns the value of `characterMap` (after it was mutated).

Comment: and this is why posting SO is more helpful than Googling things. I wouldn't have learned about the comma trick otherwise. thanks